# Netty socket.shutdownOutput() equivalent to avoid TCP RST?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, netty

I am wondering if there is a way to avoid having a TCP RST flag set as opposed to a TCP FIN flag when closing a connection in Netty where there is input data remaining in the TCP receive buffer.

The use case is:

- Client (written in C) sends data packets containing many fields.
- Server reads packets, encounters an error on an early field, throws an exception.
- Exception handler catches the exception, writes an error message, and adds the close on write callback to the write future.

The problem is:

Remaining data in the receive buffer causes Linux (or Java..) to flag the TCP packets with the RST flag.  This prevents the client from reading the data since when it gets around to trying it finds it has a read error due to the socket being closed.

With a straight Java socket, I believe the solution would be to call socket.shutdownOutput() before closing.  Is there an equivalent function in Netty or way around this?

If I simply continue reading from the socket, it may not be enough to avoid the RST since there may or may not be data in the buffer exactly when close is called.

For reference: http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/TCPRST.pdf

UPDATE:

Another reference and description of the problem:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/articles/connection_release.html

Calling shutdownOutput() should help with a more orderly closing of the connection (by sending a FIN), but if the client is still sending data then RST messages will be sent regardless (see answer from EJP.  A shutdownOutput() equivalent may be available in Netty 4+.

Solutions are either to read all data from the client (but you can never be sure when the client will fully stop sending, especially in the case of a malicious client), or to simply wait before closing the connection after sending the response (see answer from irreputable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this: after server writes the error message, wait for 500ms, then close(). See if the client can receive the error message now.

I'm guessing that the packets in the server receive buffer have not been ACK-ed, due to TCP delayed acknowledgement. If close() is called now, the proper response for these packets is RST. But if shutdownOutput() is invoked, it's a graceful close process; the packets are ACK-ed first.

---

EDIT: another attempt after learning more about the matter:

The application protocol is, the server can respond anytime, even while the client request is still being streamed. Therefore the client should, assuming blocking mode, have a separate thread reading from server. As soon as the client reads a response from server, it needs to barge into the writing thread, to stop further writing to the server. This can be done by simply close() the socket.

On the server side, if the response is written before all request data are read, and close() is called afterwards, most likely RST will be sent to client. Apparently most TCP stacks send RST to the other end if close() is called when the receive buffer isn't empty. Even if the TCP stack doesn't do that, very likely more data will arrive immediately after close(), triggering RST anyway.

When that happens, the client will very likely fail to read the server response, hence the problem.

So the server can't immediately close() after response, it needs to wait till client receives the response. How does the server know that?

First, how does the client know that it has received the full response? That is, how is the response terminated? If response is terminated by TCP FIN, the server must send FIN after response, by calling shutdownOutput(). If the response is self-terminated, e.g. by HTTP Content-Length header, the server needs not to call shutdownOutput().

After the client receives the full response, per protocol, it should promptly quit sending more data to the server. This is done by crudely sever the connection; the protocol didn't design a more elegant way. Either FIN or RST is fine.

So the server, after writing the response, should keep reading from the client, till EOF or error. Then it can close() the socket.

However, there should be a timeout for this step, to account for malicious/broken clients and network problems. Several seconds should be sufficient to complete the step in most cases.

Also, the server may not want to read from the client, since it isn't free. The server can simply wait past the timeout, then close().

Comment: That is on the list of workarounds to attempt..  but the problem is it opens up a race condition where the client could still fail depending on the network conditions or how much data it is sending after the bad field.  Ideally I want to avoid any possible race conditions, and it feels like this should be a solved problem (send a response and close the connection).

Comment: the important thing here is that the client receives the error message. we don't care about the state of the connection after that.

Comment: the client "receives" the response message now, on the OS layer, but not before it can actually read it since it is wiped by the RST packet.  The problem is that the client is sending MB of data, so it could be awhile before it reads, and even if it reads immediately, networking issues could mean the 500ms delayed RST packet ends up arriving at the same time as the earlier error message packet.  However, I do agree that this is a workaround that should work for most cases, but if it is possible, something with guaranteed consistency would be preferred.

Comment: same problems exist even with shutdownOutput()

Comment: @irreputable No it doesn't. The client can keep sending forever after receiving a FIN due to `shutdownOutput()`. Your other guesswork is astray as well. The problem isn;t caused by unacknowledged packets: it is caused by the client continuing to send: it receives RSTs sent by the server because the connection being sent to no longer exists. If he uses `shutdownOutput()` instead of `close()`, the connection *does* exist and won't provoke RSTs.

Comment: @EJP he will call close() after shutdownOutput()

Comment: Accepted since something similar to what you recommend is the only real viable solution.  Even with a shutdownOutput equivalent, the call to close() would still have to be delayed in order to prevent RST messages from being sent upon receipt of further data.  I believe that a shutdownOutput() call would however help in notifying the client before the close() call for a more graceful shutdown, but it is not possible in Netty 3.x.x (afaik), but appears that it should be possible in netty 4+ (currently alpha).

Comment: @increment The solution isn't a pointless delay: the solution is not to send  data that can't be read. This is an application protocol error.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get hold of the underlying `SocketChannel` from Netty, which I am no expert about, you can call `channel.socket().shutdownOutput().`

> Remaining data in the receive buffer causes Linux (or Java..) to flag
>   the TCP packets with the RST flag. This prevents the client from
>   reading the data since when it gets around to trying it finds it has a
>   read error due to the socket being closed.

I don't understand this. TCP guarantees that the client will receive all the data in its socket receive buffer before he gets the FIN. If you are talking about the *server's* socket receive buffer, it will be thrown away by the close(), and *further* attempts by the client to send will get an RST which becomes  an `IOException:` connection reset', because there is no connection to associate it with and therefore nowhere to put it. NB It is TCP that does all this, not Java.

But it seems to me you should read the whole request *before* closing the channel if it's bad.

You could also try increasing the socket receive buffer so it is big enough to hold an entire request. That ensures that the client won't still be sending when you want to close the connection. *EDIT:* I see the request is megabytes so this won't work.

Comment: I do not think it is possible (in the current version of Netty) to get access to the equivalent of shutdownOutput().  You are correct that TCP (well, the OS really) is sending the RST upon receipt of further data.  The issue is essentially a timing issue with when close is called.

Comment: Also, just wanted to say thank you for the additional clarity.  Answer upvoted, but I accepted the other answer since a delay timer before close is the practical implementation solution (would work with shutdownOutput as well, I think, but unable to do so).

Comment: @increment1 Adding a delay won't make the slightest difference, and any answer that says otherwise is incorrect.

Comment: Adding a delay makes a practical difference but does not achieve theoretical perfection.  There is certainly still the possibility for error, but the delay allows for a window of opportunity where the client can read the response before it is lost.  It will not work every time, but it is better than the alternative of always reading the entire message which could possibly be from a malicious client and never end.  A broken client in this case has a chance to see the cause of the error, and a malicious client is cut off before sending too much data.

Comment: @TrevorFreeman The problem here is the close while incoming unread data exists. No delay is going to eliminate that. Adding a delay makes no difference at all. The semantics of TCP/IP connection closures are not affected by arbitrary delays in the application. Sleeps in network programming are just literally a waste of time.